# how to execute a cmd in sql?

Tags: php, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sys_exec but not able to find the right way to execute in right way, Please Anyone helps me that's better for me. I am using Oracle sql

Following is my code.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER sms_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE lclcmd CHAR(255);
 res VARCHAR(255);
 BEGIN

   lclcmd := CONCAT('php C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.php','something');
  res := sys_exec(lclcmd);

END;
/
```

Comment: Is the PHP installation folder in the PATH? Was MySQL server restarted after you modified the PATH?

Comment: yes, this is the PHP installation folder PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL UDF sys\_exec() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587333/mysql-udf-sys-exec-doesnt-work)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Oracle sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be simply missing a space between the `.php` file and the parameter. With your code, the invocation command line would look like this;

```
php C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.phpsomething
```

I doubt you have a file with that name. Add a space after `.php` and see what happens:

```
lclcmd := CONCAT('php C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.php ','something');
```

Do post the error messages you may be receiving.

Comment: I am using like this   lclcmd := CONCAT('php ','C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.php');

Comment: @ALPHA This is not what your question says. In any event, try specifying the full path to php

Comment: this is the full path to PHP, While executing from windows command prompt line is executing perfectly.

Comment: @ALPHA No, this is not the full path; the full path would be something like `C:\PHP7.1\bin\php.exe` and not just `php`

Comment: here I am running a file.

Comment: @ALPHA No, you are not running a file. You are running php interpreter, passing your file as a parameter. Here's a simple test: open a new command prompt and type `php` followed by Enter - what do you get?

Comment: Nothing the cmd stops there itself.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. Now what happens if you invoke your command line: `php C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.php`?

Comment: File is executing getting output too.

Comment: Then what happens when you try to invoke your sys_exec? With a simple `select sys_exec('php C:/xampp/htdocs/sample/sms_send.php')` in mysql console

Comment: I am not getting but someone said about UTL_HTTP.